# Firebase Authentication: how to verify user still exists

Tags: android, firebase, exception, firebase-authentication, android-task

I am using Firebase Anonymous Authentication.

In case a user has been deleted from the Firebase console, the client still believes the user exists, as it still holds the token.

Each time I start the app, I would like to verify if the user still exists. I found out I can use the `FirebaseUser.reload()` function.

The documentation says that in case the user's account has been disabled or deleted, the `FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException` will be thrown:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#reload()

However this is an asyncronous function, and I am struggling finding out how to catch this exception. Can anyone show me a code sample on how to catch this exception?
I have looked all documentation, but I haven't found a sample about this.

Comment: You have user data inside database?

Comment: @BrunoFerreira that shouldn't matter. I would just like to catch that exception.

Comment: Can you add your firebaseUser.reload() method?

Comment: The point is that I would like to catch that exception, but I don't know how to do that in an asyncronous function. Can anyone show how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
mFirebaseUser.reload().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {
            Log.d(TheApp.LOG_TAG, "user doesn't exist anymore");
            createUser();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: great thanks, it works by using `addOnFailureListener`